# ¿Cómo resuelvo o que otra opción tengo para filtrar el data set en lenguaje R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataset

Estaba haciendo la partición de los datos para entrenar un pequeño modelo de machine learnig, pero tengo este error al establecer el test... (Todo el código esta hecho en lenguaje R, y soy algo novato para esto). Adjunto código y su respectivo error.

```
names(acciones.sc)[1] = "Precio"
names(acciones.sc)[2] = "Fecha"

acciones.sc$Fecha = as.Date(acciones.sc$Fecha)

set.seed(1994) 

train = createDataPartition(na.omit(subset(acciones, acciones$Fecha_dup < today())$Precio,
 p = 0.7, list = F    ))

test = rbind(acciones[ -train, ] , subset(acciones,acciones$Fecha_dup >= today())) # esta es la linea del error. Y el error es: "Error in -train: invalid argument to unary operator
Traceback:

1. rbind(acciones[-train, ], subset(acciones, acciones$Fecha_dup >= 
 .     today()))
2. acciones[-train, ]
3. `[.data.frame`(acciones, -train, )"
test.sc = as.data.frame(cbind(test$Precio,test$Fecha_dup, scale(test[,c(2,3,4)])))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Puedes poner qué te devuelve cuando ejecutas `train`?

Comment: Creo que tienes un error tipografico: en varios lugares indicas `acciones` pero entiendo que debería ser `acciones.sc`

Comment: Lo que da train es '$Resample1 =
12346811141718192627303132333438394044464750525456576162646567687073748082878990919596979899100101102103104105106107108110113114115117118119120122124125126127129131133135136137138139140141143148149151154156157161162164167168170171173175179181182183186187188193194198200206207212214215216220222223224227235237242245248249251252254257258260261262263264265267271277279280282289291297298302307308310316317319321322325326327328331332333335336339340344347348351352353355356358362364366368370374377380382383385389392393396397398399400401402404405⋯'